# Почему возникает ошибка? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at Object.displayMessage (game.js:4)

Tags: javascript

Учу js по книге Эрика Фримена. В 8 главе делают игру морской бой на js. Пишу код идентично, но возникает ошибка:

> game.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
>       at Object.displayMessage (game.js:4).

Если что могу докинуть код

```
var view = {
displayMessage: function(msg) {
    var messageArea = document.getElementById('#messageArea');
    messageArea.innerHTML = msg;
},

displayHit: function(location) {
    var cell = document.getElementById(location);
    cell.setAttribute("class", "hit");
},

displayMiss: function(location) {
    var cell = document.getElementById(location);
    cell.setAttribute("class", "miss");
}
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас на странице нет элемента с `id="#messageArea"`. Может быть у вас есть элемент с `id="messageArea"`, но тогда нужно писать

```
var messageArea = document.getElementById('messageArea');
```

(без начального `#`)

Comment: Спасибо! Так и было

Comment: @ИванСорокин Если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его как верный